# App tutorial or guide in Sencha Touch

Tags: sencha-touch

I've been trying to find some info about this but the combination of words just doesn't help as it just so I figured I'd might as well ask it in here.

I'm developing a sencha touch app and I want to show the user how to use my app. But those messages should obviously only be displayed on the app's first run. Does any of you have any idea of how to achieve this in sencha touch?

Haven't tried anything as I have no idea where to start and as I mentioned earlier looking this up on google just returns tutorials about Sencha Touch.

Answer (score 1):

you can set a flag and save it to the localstorage. 
On every app launch you can check for that flag and only create the guide view if needed